# Creating an authentication ticket

Tags: sinch

how can i generate an authentication ticket for sinch using the javascript (plz no nodejs) i'm using parse for user authentication then i would like to pass that session to sinch

add these crypto libs to your html file

```html
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-utf16-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

```
    var userTicket = {
                        'identity': {'type': 'username', 'endpoint': user._serverData.username},
                        'expiresIn': 3600,
                    'applicationKey': sinchClient.applicationKey,
                        'created': new Date().toISOString()
                }



                    var userTicketJson = JSON.stringify(userTicket).trim();
                    var userTicketBase64 = btoa(userTicketJson);


   // TicketSignature = Base64 ( HMAC-SHA256 ( ApplicationSecret, UTF8 ( UserTicketJson ) ) )




                var digest = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(appSecret,userTicketJson);
               var signature =  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(digest);



    // UserTicket = TicketData + ":" + TicketSignature
              var  signedUserTicket = userTicketBase64.replace('=','') + ':' + signature.replace('=','');




                    sinchClient.start({'userTicket':signedUserTicket})
                        .then(function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                        })
                        .fail(function(error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        });
```

Answer (score 5):

The preferred way is to generate the authentication ticket on a backend or in an environment which you control, not on the client - for security reasons! For generating the ticket in Javascript, there is a reference implementation in Javascript available for node (portable to the browser manually or using browserify): https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinch-ticketgen

The authentication ticket generator is also included in the Sinch JS SDK for development, testing and server-side purposes. Simply provide "applicationSecret" in addition to "applicationKey" when instantiating the SinchClient and you can now start the sinchClient with any user identity.

**Example:**

```
sinchClient = new SinchClient({
    applicationKey: 'SOME_APPLICATION_KEY',
    applicationSecret: 'SOME_APPLICATION_SECRET',
});

sinchClient.start({username: 'SOME_USERNAME'});
```

However, keep in mind that this should **not be done on client side in a production environment**, since your application secret would be open and it would be trivial for an attacker to take advantage of.

Instead, please make sure you generate the authentication ticket in a secure environment where only you have access to your application secret.

Comment: Thanks but i found out a method without using nodejs :)

Comment: @OseiFortune can you please mention the method?